# Как сохранить созданное изображение в папку на сервере?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой код, который меняет размер у фотографии, как мне сохранить его в указанную папку?

```
$path = '/var/www/www-root/data/';  
$file = 'http://site.ru/image.jpg';   
$image = new Imagick($file);
$image->cropThumbnailImage( 163, 152 );
echo $image;
```

При выводе $image в браузере появляется следующее (как мне это сохранить в папку?):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$image->writeImage($path."name.jpg");` сохранит изображение

Comment: imagejpeg($image, 'image.jpg'); https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: InDevX, спасибо, все работает! Весь гугл перелопатил. imagejpeg пробовал, ничего не сохранял вообще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании объектов `Imagick` в php, сохранять изображение можно с использованием функции `writeImage()` (в аргументы принимает имя файла)

```
$image->writeImage($path."name.jpg");
```

Где $path это ваша переменная `$path = '/var/www/www-root/data/';`, к которой добавляется имя файла.

Answer (score 1):

докинь `header('content-type: image/jpeg');` перед `echo $image;`, чтобы изображение выводилось как изображение, а не текст